# Clipping layer with every feature in another layer using ModelBuilder

Tags: arcmap, modelbuilder, clip, arcgis-10.5, splitting

Currently working with ArcMap 10.5, from a gdb, and using ModelBuilder. My python knowledge is null.

I have a road layer (line), and then a city limits layer (polygon) with various feauters (up to 30) each being a department of it. What I'm trying to achieve seems pretty simple but I am unable to find the way.

I want to clip the road layer with the city layer in a way that it creates a new road layer in the shape of every department. Something like this:

- Road_1
- Road_2
- Road_3
- Road_...
- Road_29
- Road_30

The next step would be to use Pivot Table on each one of these layers to know how many metres there are for each road level (1-5).

Is there any tool that does this kind of clip in a single process? I'm working on a ModelBuilder so I'd rather not have to add the same process 30 times unless it's absolutely necessary.

Comment: The Split tool does this but it needs an Advanced level license. ModelBuilder and Python can provide workaround for Basic and Stsndard.

Answer (score 0):

I think the ModelBuilder tool/function you are looking for is called an "[Iterator](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/analyze/modelbuilder/a-quick-tour-of-using-iterators-for-iteration-looping-.htm)", which allow you to repeat the same function over and over.

[image]

Based on the description above, and the options you have to choose from in 10.5, I think you probably will use the "[Iterate Feature Selection](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/tools/modelbuilder-toolbox/iterate-feature-selection.htm)".

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the union function. That will split the roads into segments based upon the departments they cross. The table will then have information that will allow you to connect each road segment to the department. You can probably use a join of some sort to connect the two.

Comment: forgot to say that the lengths of each segment should be calculated automatically. If not, you can add a field and use the Calculate geometry tool.

Comment: Actually an Intersection might be the tool to use.